# POWER function in SQL Server with negative numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I would like to calculate the the third root of negative number using POWER function (in SQL Server 2019)

```
SELECT POWER(-8.000, 1.000 / 3)
```

but I keep getting this error:

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

It works fine for positive numbers.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: It might also be worth raising this as a bug in [Azure Feedback for SQL Server](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an explanation of why your cube root call to `POWER` is not working.  However, given that the input is a negative number (`-8`), the output should be equivalent to the negative of the cube root of the positive input:

```
SELECT -1.0*POWER(8.000, 1.000 / 3) AS output;
```

This outputs `-2.000` as expected.  You could even write more general logic to workaround this problem:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN input > 0 THEN POWER(input, 1.000 / 3)
         ELSE -1.0*POWER(-1.0*input, 1.000 / 3) END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your calculation doesn't work is because:

```
(-8)^(1/3)              --> an integer, -2
(-8)^(0.33333333333333) --> a complex number
```

That is, floating point values are inexact and cannot represent something like one-third.  And the value has to be *exactly* 1/3 in order for the value to be a floating point number.

If you know the value is representable as a floating point value, then you can use:

```
sign(-8) * power(abs(-8), 1.0 / 3)
```

Note:  This does not work for all cases.  Trivially:

```
sign(-4) * power(abs(-4), 1.0 / 2)
```

will return -2, which is not the correct answer.